# Small signal analysis - Flyback transfer function - LTspice

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, flyback, small-signal

I am trying to simulate the transfer function of a Flyback by using LTspice. The flyback that I am trying to simulate is a flyback which can be found into the book "Switch mode power supplies" written by Christophe Basso. (I recommand to every one who wants to understand power electronics to read it and I particurlaly appreciate the small signal analysis part).

I would like to observe the plant transfer function of the flyback. If I correctly understand what is written in the book, it should be (if the flyback is working in CCM, what I supposed to be as regards of the bode plot seen in the book):

$$\frac{Vout(s)}{Verr(s)} = H_{flyback}(s) = \frac{G_0(1+\frac{s}{wz_1})(1-\frac{s}{wz_2})}{1+\frac{s}{wp_1}}$$

Here is my LTspice circuit :

[image]

and its parameters :

[image]

I know that my simulation is not working as regards of the tranfer function, the bode plot does not fit the transfer function.

Here is my result :

[image]

Whatever the result I have a problem at the beginning that I am not able to understand :

```
Singular deck expression: "rled"=1.#INF
Circuit: * C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\WK\LTspice\Flyback stability\Example.asc

Direct Newton iteration failed to find .op point.  (Use ".option noopiter" to skip.)
Starting Gmin stepping
Gmin = 10
Gmin = 1.07374
Gmin = 0.115292
Gmin = 0.0123794
Gmin = 0.00132923
Gmin = 0.000142725
Gmin = 1.5325e-005
Gmin = 1.6455e-006
Gmin = 1.76685e-007
Gmin = 1.89714e-008
Gmin = 2.03704e-009
Gmin = 2.18725e-010
Gmin = 2.34854e-011
Gmin = 2.52173e-012
Gmin = 2.70769e-013
Gmin = 0
Gmin stepping succeeded in finding the operating point.

Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(u2:11)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(u2:11)

Date: Sat Nov 14 17:50:28 2020
Total elapsed time: 0.075 seconds.

tnom = 27
temp = 27
method = trap
totiter = 439
traniter = 0
tranpoints = 0
accept = 0
rejected = 0
matrix size = 47
fillins = 38
solver = Normal
Matrix Compiler1:     196 opcodes
Matrix Compiler2: off  [0.4]/0.7/1.3
```

Can somebody can tell me what is the problem in my simulation ?

Here is the text file of my simulation :

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1704 1176
WIRE 272 -80 -48 -80
WIRE 480 -80 304 -80
WIRE 272 32 272 -80
WIRE 304 32 304 -80
WIRE 768 112 336 112
WIRE 1168 112 912 112
WIRE 1344 112 1232 112
WIRE 1568 112 1344 112
WIRE -48 144 -48 -80
WIRE 1344 144 1344 112
WIRE 480 208 480 -80
WIRE 1568 208 1568 112
WIRE 432 224 416 224
WIRE 272 256 272 144
WIRE 432 272 416 272
WIRE 960 272 912 272
WIRE 1344 288 1344 224
WIRE -48 384 -48 224
WIRE 272 384 272 336
WIRE 272 384 -48 384
WIRE 416 384 416 272
WIRE 416 384 272 384
WIRE 480 384 480 288
WIRE 480 384 416 384
WIRE 768 384 768 272
WIRE 768 384 480 384
WIRE 800 384 768 384
WIRE 960 384 960 272
WIRE 960 384 800 384
WIRE 1344 384 1344 352
WIRE 1344 384 960 384
WIRE 1568 384 1568 288
WIRE 1568 384 1344 384
WIRE -48 400 -48 384
WIRE 800 432 800 384
WIRE 1568 528 1568 480
WIRE 1568 528 1312 528
WIRE 800 592 800 512
WIRE 1312 624 1312 528
WIRE 1568 624 1568 528
WIRE 480 736 480 576
WIRE 608 736 480 736
WIRE 800 736 800 672
WIRE 800 736 688 736
WIRE 1040 736 800 736
WIRE 1040 768 1040 736
WIRE 1312 768 1312 704
WIRE 1312 768 1264 768
WIRE 480 800 480 736
WIRE 1312 864 1264 864
WIRE 1424 864 1312 864
WIRE 1568 864 1568 704
WIRE 1568 864 1488 864
WIRE 800 912 800 736
WIRE 1312 912 1312 864
WIRE 480 944 480 864
WIRE 1568 960 1568 864
WIRE 1568 960 1376 960
WIRE 1568 1008 1568 960
WIRE 480 1104 480 1024
WIRE 800 1104 800 976
WIRE 800 1104 480 1104
WIRE 1040 1104 1040 864
WIRE 1040 1104 800 1104
WIRE 1312 1104 1312 1008
WIRE 1312 1104 1040 1104
WIRE 1568 1104 1568 1088
WIRE 1568 1104 1312 1104
WIRE 1568 1136 1568 1104
FLAG -48 400 0
FLAG 1568 112 Vout
FLAG 1568 480 Vout
FLAG 1568 1136 0
FLAG 480 576 Verr
FLAG 416 224 Verr
SYMBOL voltage -48 128 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 90
SYMBOL ind 256 240 R0
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value {Lp}
SYMBOL PWM\\PWM-CM 288 80 M90
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMATTR SpiceLine2 Lsw={Lp} Fsw=65kHz
SYMATTR Value2 RISense=0.7 Slope={Se}
SYMBOL DC_Transformer_Model 800 192 R0
WINDOW 39 41 142 Bottom 2
SYMATTR SpiceLine n = -166m
SYMATTR InstName X1
SYMATTR Value n = -166m
SYMBOL diode 1168 128 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value Dmbr20200ct
SYMBOL res 1328 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 20m
SYMBOL cap 1328 288 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 2040µ
SYMBOL res 1552 192 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 7.2
SYMBOL res 1552 608 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value {Rupper}
SYMBOL res 1552 992 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value {Rlower}
SYMBOL res 1296 608 R0
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value {Rled}
SYMBOL AC_optocoupler_model 1136 816 R0
WINDOW 39 -42 -119 Bottom 2
SYMATTR SpiceLine Vf = 0.6 CTR = {CTR} Copto = 0
SYMATTR InstName X2
SYMBOL cap 1488 848 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value {Czero}
SYMBOL ind 592 752 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L2
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL cap 784 912 R0
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value {Cpole}
SYMBOL voltage 800 528 R180
WINDOW 0 24 96 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 16 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL res 784 576 R0
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value {Rpullup}
SYMBOL cap 464 800 R0
SYMATTR InstName C4
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL voltage 480 928 R0
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value ""
SYMBOL TL431 1312 960 R0
SYMATTR InstName U2
SYMBOL e 480 192 R0
WINDOW 3 12 127 Left 2
SYMATTR Value {controller_divider}
SYMATTR InstName E1
TEXT -1384 -72 Left 2 !.param Vout = 12 Vref = 2.5
TEXT -1376 -120 Left 2 ;Parameters
TEXT -1384 -16 Left 2 !.param Ibridge = 250u Rlower =Vref/Ibridge Rupper = (Vout-Vref)/Ibridge
TEXT -1384 40 Left 2 !.param Lp = 450u Se = 100m
TEXT -1384 144 Left 2 !.param fc = 1k pm = 60 Gfc = -20 pfc = -85
TEXT -1376 120 Left 2 ;Gfc = Gaint of the plant transfer function at fc H(fc) and pfc = Phi(H(fc))
TEXT -1384 200 Left 2 !.param G = 10^(-Gfc/20) boost = pm-(pfc)-90 pi=3.14159 K=tan((boost/2+45)*pi/180)
TEXT -1384 256 Left 2 !.param Fzero = fc/k Fpole = k*fc
TEXT -1384 312 Left 2 !.param Rpullup = 20k Rled = CTR*Rpullup/G Czero=1/(2*pi*Fzero*Rupper) Cpole=1/(2*pi*Fpole*Rpullup)
TEXT -1384 360 Left 2 !.param CTR = 2 controller_divider = 1/3
TEXT -1392 480 Left 2 !.MODEL Dmbr20200ct d\n+IS=2.13004e-07 RS=0.01 N=1.51125 EG=1.03726\n+XTI=0.508834 BV=200 IBV=0.0001 CJO=8.07754e-10\n+VJ=0.4 M=0.454959 FC=0.5 TT=1e-09\n+KF=0 AF=1
TEXT -1424 1160 Left 2 !.ac dec 100 10 100k
RECTANGLE Normal -128 400 -1424 -160 2
```

Thank you very much and have a nice day !

Comment: In your `G` parameter definition, you're incorrectly using the carrot (`^`) symbol for exponentiation instead of the required double asterisk (`**`).  Looks like this is causing a divide by zero when it tries to use that `G` to evaluate `Rled`.

Comment: Thank you so much ! :D I would never notice it as a problem ...